# How to deselect a radio button on click using Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I want to deselect a radio button using a Cancel button's click event using Angular/TypeScript.

setupproduct.component.html:

```
<app-panel header="{{ 'Setup Approval' }}" fullHeight="true">
  <div class="panel-content">
      <form  #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" class='formgroup'>

    <div class="col-xs-11">
      <div class="panel-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-list">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>product Name</th>
              <th>product Price</th>
              <th>Submitted By</th>
              <th>Time Submitted</th>
              <th>Approve</th>
              <th>Decline</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

            <tr *ngFor="let product of products;let idx = index;let idy = count;" >
              <td>&nbsp;{{product.productName}}</td>
              <td>&nbsp;{{product.productPrice}}</td>
              <td>&nbsp;{{product.modifiedBy}}</td>
              <td>&nbsp;{{product.modifiedTime| date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm a'}}</td>
              <!--<td *ngFor="let radioOption of data.radioOption">-->
              <td >
                <div class="col-md-2 form-group  bottom-buffer-radio">
                    <input type="hidden" id="deal" name='deal' [(ngModel)] = 'selectedDeal' />
                    <div class="radio radio-inline" >
                      <input type="radio" name='radiogroup1' value="APPROVED"   [id]="idx"

                      (change)="onSelectionChange(product,$event.target.value)">
                      <label [for]=idx></label>
                    </div>
                  </div>
              </td>

              <td >
                  <div class="col-md-2 form-group  bottom-buffer-radio">
                      <div class="radio radio-inline" >
                        <input type="radio" name='radiogroup1' value="DECLINED"  [id]="idy+idx"
                      (change)="onSelectionChange(product,$event.target.value)">
                        <label [for]=idy+idx></label>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
     </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)='cancelSelection()' type="button">Cancel</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  </div>
</app-panel>
```

Comment: on your cancelSelection method set the radio button value = '' `(blank)`

Comment: Can you tell me how?